# Search bar in duplicate (wordpress/php/bootstrap)

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, duplicates, notepad++

due to some reason I'm getting the search bar in duplicate.
I suspect I have a double function command somewhere...but I can not find it. Can someone look at the code with "fresh eyes" and try to find my mistake?
as wordpress keeps giving me 2 search bars instead of one
I am using Notepad++, Bootstrap v 3.0 and Wordpress 4.7.8

Here is the code

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">

        <div class="row text-center no-margin">

        <?php 
        $currentPage = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array('posts_per_page' => 3,'post_type'=>'post', 'paged' => $currentPage);
        new WP_Query($args);
        if( have_posts() ): $i = 0;

            while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

                <?php 
                    if($i==0): $column = 12; $class = '';
                    elseif($i > 0 && $i <= 2): $column = 6; $class = ' second-row-padding';
                    elseif($i > 2): $column = 4; $class = ' third-row-padding';
                    endif;

                ?>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>

                    <div class="col-xs-<?php echo $column; echo $class; ?> blog-item">
                        <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ):
                            $urlImg = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) );
                        endif; ?>
                        <div class="blog-element" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $urlImg; ?>);">

                            <!--<?php the_title( sprintf('<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ),'</a></h1>' ); ?> -->
                             <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                            <small><?php the_category(' '); ?></small>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>

            <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
                <?php next_posts_link('« Older Posts'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts »'); ?>
            </div>

        <?php endif;
                wp_reset_query();
        ?>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: your code seems to have missing parts (and not really formatted). By the way, what template are you using (if it is your custom one, please include the part where search bar is called)?

Comment: <form role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
 <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="Search" />
</form>

Comment: yeas i am using custom template.  That code is from my index.php and i've understood that it is the "heart  of template"

Comment: yes, this code should display only one search bar, i don't see it in your `index.php`, did you add this code (the search bar one) anywhere in your template files? There should be one by default in the sidebar, if i remember well (`sidebar.php`, but depends on what was the base of the template), if you added one, it could duplicate. Check also if you don't have a `searchform.php` included somewhere, which also adds this form

Comment: I can't see the search bar being outputted anywhere in your code. If the search bar is in the header you will need to show us the HTML/PHP of the `header.php` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

I have disabled the `//get_sidebar();`

```
        <?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">

        <div class="row text-center no-margin">

        <?php 
        $currentPage = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array('posts_per_page' => 3,'post_type'=>'post', 'paged' => $currentPage);
        new WP_Query($args);
        if( have_posts() ): $i = 0;

            while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

                <?php 
                    if($i==0): $column = 12; $class = '';
                    elseif($i > 0 && $i <= 2): $column = 6; $class = ' second-row-padding';
                    elseif($i > 2): $column = 4; $class = ' third-row-padding';
                    endif;

                ?>


                    <div class="col-xs-<?php echo $column; echo $class; ?> blog-item">
                        <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ):
                            $urlImg = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) );
                        endif; ?>
                        <div class="blog-element" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $urlImg; ?>);">

                            <!--<?php the_title( sprintf('<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ),'</a></h1>' ); ?> -->
                             <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                             <?php the_content(); ?>

                            <small><?php the_category(' '); ?></small>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>

            <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
                <?php next_posts_link('« Older Posts'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts »'); ?>
            </div>

        <?php endif;
                wp_reset_query();
        ?>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <?php //get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help you. your previous question screenshot helped to find out the issue.