# Page title and content in wrong order (wordpress/bootstrap/php)

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, html

I'm having problem with my Wordpress 4.7.8 localhost custom-theme webpage.
As hard as I try, I keep getting "Title" where content should be and the content at the place of the title
[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrFqK.jpg)
Here is how it looks in wordpress admin dashboard:
[...and image the view in wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBEt0.jpg)

any Ideas where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

[Search bar in duplicate (wordpress/php/bootstrap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647633/search-bar-in-duplicate-wordpress-php-bootstrap)

This code taken from your previous question.

this code for displaying title `<?php the_title(); ?>` and this code displaying content `<?php the_content(); ?>`. you can replace this code wherever you want.

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">

            <div class="row text-center no-margin">

            <?php 
            $currentPage = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args = array('posts_per_page' => 3,'post_type'=>'post', 'paged' => $currentPage);
            new WP_Query($args);
            if( have_posts() ): $i = 0;

                while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

                    <?php 
                        if($i==0): $column = 12; $class = '';
                        elseif($i > 0 && $i <= 2): $column = 6; $class = ' second-row-padding';
                        elseif($i > 2): $column = 4; $class = ' third-row-padding';
                        endif;

                    ?>


                        <div class="col-xs-<?php echo $column; echo $class; ?> blog-item">
                            <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ):
                                $urlImg = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) );
                            endif; ?>
                            <div class="blog-element" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $urlImg; ?>);">

                                <!--<?php the_title( sprintf('<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ),'</a></h1>' ); ?> -->
                                 <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                                 <?php the_content(); ?>

                                <small><?php the_category(' '); ?></small>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>

                <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
                    <?php next_posts_link('« Older Posts'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                    <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts »'); ?>
                </div>

            <?php endif;
                    wp_reset_query();
            ?>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the issue of having title and page content in the wrong order. Now I just have to solve my double post issue :)

Comment: Glad to help you .. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to edit content-single.php file to change the post content order. Your post content is loading first before post title.

Check if ,

```
the_content() or get_the_content()
```

is showing before ,

```
get_the_title() or the_title()
```